# The best way of getting results from handler

Tags: java

I have a question about handlers. Is there a standard way of getting result from them?
For example I have such handler interface (Java):

```
interface SomeHandler {

    void handleData(Object data);
}
```

And it's implementation:

```
public class MyHandler implements SomeHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleData(Object data){
        //Some actions
    }
}
```

And I have some external class with a method, which requests a handler for parsing it's results. This class is a part of some API, so I can't rewrite it.

```
public class SomeClass{

    public void getResults(SomeHandler handler){
        Object[] dataArray = loadData();
        for(Object dataItem : dataArray){
            handler.handleData(dataItem);
        }
    }

    private Object[] loadData(){
        //Some internal actions
    }
}
```

So, what is the best way of collecting data from this handler?

I have two ideas:

1)

```
public class MyFirstHandler implements SomeHandler {

    private List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();

    @Override
    public void handleData(Object data){
        result.add(data);
    }

    public List<Object> getResult(){
        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
 SomeClass someClass = //received from some external code
 MyFirstHandler handler = new MyFirstHandler();
 someClass.getResults(handler);
 List<Object> result = handler.getResult();
```

2)

```
public class MySecondHandler implements SomeHandler {

    private List<Object> resultContainer;

    public MySecondHandler(List<Object> resultContainer){
        this.resultContainer= resultContainer;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleData(Object data){
        resultContainer.add(data);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
 SomeClass someClass = //received from some external code
 List<Object> resultContainer = new ArrayList<Object>();
 MySecondHandler handler = new MySecondHandler(resultContainer);
 someClass.getResults(handler);
 //results are in the resultContainer now
```

Which one is the best? Or maybe there is some other way?

Comment: Why do you want to save the data in the handler? Why not just return it after processing? I don't think that the handler is not going to use this data at any later point of time - correct? Why create new instances each time, in that case.

Comment: @TJ-, I mean, SomeClass - is not my own class, but a part of some external API. So I have to use handlers to get results from it.

Comment: You mean `SomeHandler`?

Comment: @TJ-, Both are. :)
`SomeClass` is an instance of some external class. And `SomeHandler` is an interface, which it wants to get from me.
Looks like my code example is too simplified. Sorry for that.

Comment: the first approch seems to be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Handler is only used for data collection and nothing else (as it should be anyway) I would go for the second approach, but slightly modified

Instead of using List, I'd use the more abstract type Collection because the Handler doesn't need to know how to store the data, it just needs a place where it can store data when they come along. Now the client of the Handler can decide how it wants the data to be stored. This separates the concern of collecting the data from how the data is actually stored. With this approach the client then has more flexibility.

So for example if it doesn't care about duplicate data it can use a HashSet instead of an ArrayList. Or it can add additional data before getting the results if necessary. It can even provide a custom implementation of Collection.